# pythonic way for implementing interface for modules

Tags: python, interface, module

I have a group of functions that define me an desired behavior (interface).

This group can be wrapped in a class, so I can "enforce" the desired behavior I want (raising not implemented errors).

But on the other hand, it is not very pythonic, and the class would be just a class with a bunch of static methods.

So if I use modules with functions, I can't enforce the module to implement all desired functions.

Any ideas how to enforce a module to implement all functions I want, without wrapping it in a class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to enforce anything? Are you asking others to implement an API?

Comment: Want to use it as part of a factory, so other part the app can just get the object dynamically, and use the same function names for different implementations

Comment: So why the need to enforce anything?

Comment: To prevent getting attribute error when using a function that not implemented

Comment: You can always inspect the module at import time to find out if the desired set of functions is defined, but that will not garantee they are "correctly" defined anyway - not more than it would be garanteed for a class actually... Also, using classes as namespaces is not necessarily unpythonic either if you have a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is for your factory to have a method for "registering" an implementation and another method for "getting" a specific implementation.  A valid implementation would be an object having the required method names.

```
class MyFactory:
    def register(self, name, implementation):
        # check implementation somehow and raise an Exception if it's not valid
        # insure implementation has all required function names and they are callable

    def get_implementation(self, name):
        # returns a previously registered implementation
```

The only thing you really accomplish here is that an invalid implementation will throw an exception when you register it, instead of throwing an exception when you use it.  Whether this sort of thing is worth the effort is questionable.  There are an infinite number of ways an implementation can fail to work properly when you use it, and registering can only catch the most obvious of them (missing function names).